# After update to 13.10: 2nd standby after opening lid

Tags: 13.10, suspend, macbook-air, xfce4-power-manager

Updated the Lubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10 on my MacBook Air. Ever since, when I open up the lid after standby, the system wakes from standby but after a few seconds it goes into standby again. There seems to be another (new) process putting my device into sleep mode now, too.

If I kill xfce4-power-manager, it only goes to standby once. However, it shouldn't go into sleep at all when xfce4-power-manager is not running.

How can I track down the new trigger of the standby mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: This is fixed in xfce4-power-manager 1.2.0-2ubuntu1.1. Install that version from saucy-updates to fix this issue without the workaround of editing `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`.

---

I have the exact same problem, see bug raised at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/1241896.

There's a similar bug with gnome-settings-daemon apparently (#1180513) and someone mentioned logind may be the culprit but currently it's not clear if that's the root cause, or if there's a workaround. Also 1180513 apparently had a fix released but users are still reporting problems.

In the meantime follow bugs 1241896 and 1222021 for a XFCE resolution.

Comment: Temporary workaround is to set:

"HandleLidSwitch=ignore"

in "/etc/systemd/logind.conf"